# Event Booking site - how to ensure over-booking doesn't occur?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, simple-form

I'm building an Event site using Ruby on Rails and I'm not sure what code I can implement to monitor the bookings so as to ensure I don't allow bookings when the number of spaces available have been filled.

I'm using simple_form to create events, this is the partial -

```
<%= simple_form_for(@event) do |f| %>
    <% if @event.errors.any? %>
        <h2><%= pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this     Event from saving:</h2>
    <ul>
        <% @event.errors.full_message.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
```

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a category"} %>
<!-- The above code loop assigns a category_id to each event -->

<%= f.input :image, as: :file, label: 'Image' %>
<%= f.input :title, label: 'Event Title' %>
<label>Location</label><%= f.text_field :location, id: 'geocomplete' %></br>
<label>Date</label><%= f.text_field :date, label: 'Date', id: 'datepicker' %>
<%= f.input :time, label: 'Time' %>
<%= f.input :description, label: 'Description' %>
<label>Number of spaces available</label><%= f.text_field :number_of_spaces, label: 'Number of spaces' %>
<%= f.input :is_free, label: 'Tick box if Event is free of charge' %>
<%= f.input :price, label: 'Cost per person (leave blank if free of charge)' %>
<%= f.input :organised_by, label: 'Organised by' %>
<%= f.input :organiser_description, label: 'Organiser description' %>
<%= f.input :url, label: "Link to Organiser site" %>

<%= f.button :submit, label: 'Submit' %>
```

I have an association between the Event and Booking model. What code should I implement to ensure that the bookings for a particular event can be monitored? I'm quite new to Rails so this has me a little stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation in model, something like this can do the trick whenever you create a new Booking record

```
validates_inclusion_of :number, :in => 0..10 # Or whatever number you want
```

Or

```
validates :number, :numericality => {:less_than_or_equal_to => 10 } # Or Whatever number you want
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this depending on how your data is modelled. And you need to provide more information about how someone books a place on the event. I'm going to make a couple of assumptions in order to give you some ideas. An Event has many Bookings, a Booking belongs to an Event. Event has a total number of spaces attribute. A booking is made for 1 space on the event.

To prevent overbooking you will want to prohibit the form from showing and add some controller logic.

In the controller create method (this will depend on your booking form which you haven't shown).

```
def create
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id)
  if @event.bookings.count >= @event.total_spaces
    flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    #some code to save the booking
  end
end
```

In the view, before the form code, add some logic

```
<% if @event.bookings.count < @event.total_spaces
```

Comment: There isn't a separate booking form, as such. The form above creates the event including a section for stipulating the number of spaces available. I have a number_of_spaces attribute in my Event model. The association between the Event and Booking models is as you describe above.

Comment: To book an event there is a box at the bottom of the event page which will take a user through to the payment page but, as you suggest I will need to write some code for free events also as over-booking could be an issue there too. The above looks pretty solid.

Comment: The same logic applies, if the event is fully booked, don't show the the box that takes users through to the payment page. If the above has helped, please mark my answer as accepted or upvote it. Thx.

Comment: Hi there, no this doesnt work. For some reason I don't think the database is logging the bookings as they're being made.

Comment: You'll need to debug why bookings aren't being saved to the d/b.

Comment: I'm not sure its a debugging issue, I think I'm missing some code that would save it.

Comment: Strictly speaking why bookings aren't being saved is a different question. When you start a new question, show what code you have for creating/saving bookings.